# Facebook Custom login UI with sdk 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

Im using this code for custom login ui from Facebook developer page, It gave me a log message "**FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter**". Kindly tell me how can i remove this

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
       if (error)
        {

        }
        else if (result.isCancelled)
        {
        }
        else
        {
           if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
            {

            }
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

On using **FBLoginManager** app gets public_profile permission automatically upon any successful login. You need not request that again. If you need email. Try

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    // Process error
  } else if (result.isCancelled) {
    // Handle cancellations
  } else {
    // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
    // should check if specific permissions missing
    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
      // Do work
    }
  }
}];
```